# Assertion failure for calculating hour difference

Tags: java, date, calendar, assertion

I am subtracting `500 hours` from Calendar Date and my method is giving difference in hours.

Why is the below assertion failing ?

**Method to test:**

```
 public long dataFetchTotalTime(long time) {
        long hours = 0;
        Calendar ackCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long diff = ackCal.getTime().getTime() - time;
        hours = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return hours;
    }
```

**Test Case:**

```
@Test
public void checkFetchTimeDiff()
{
    long expected = 500;
    Client client = new Client();
    Calendar ackCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    ackCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -500);
    long actual = client.dataFetchTotalTime(ackCal.getTime().getTime());
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

**Error Trace:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<500> but was:<514>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake:

```
ackCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -500);
```

**Method to test:**

```
 public long dataFetchTotalTime(long time) {
        long hours = 0;
        Calendar ackCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long diff = ackCal.getTime().getTime() - time;
        hours = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return hours;
    }
```

**Test Case:**

```
@Test
public void checkFetchTimeDiff()
{
    long expected = 500;
    Client client = new Client();
    Calendar ackCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    ackCal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -500);
    long actual = client.dataFetchTotalTime(ackCal.getTime().getTime());
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;
System.out.println(
    Duration
    .between(
        now , 
        now.plusHours( 500L ) 
    )
    .toHours()
) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/VJtGa8).

> 500

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `ZonedDateTime`

The `Calendar` class, well actually its commonly used subclass, `GregorianCalendar`, is replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). The `ZonedDateTime` class represents a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region. In other words, a date, with a time-of-day, in the context of a time zone.

You can convert if need be, but best to avoid the legacy date-time classes entirely. To convert, call new methods added to the old classes.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = ( GregorianCalendar ) myJavaUtilCalendar  ;  // Cast from the more general to the concrete.
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;  // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
```

To capture the current moment, specify your desired time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

### `Duration`

Do your math. Represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline as either a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds, or `Period` on a scale of years-months-days.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 500 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( d ) ;
```

To determine elapsed time, use [`Duration.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)).

```
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( zdt , zdtLater ) ;
```

To view as text in standard ISO 8601 format, call `toString`.

```
String output = elapsed.toString() ;
```

To view elapsed time as a total number of hours, call [`Duration::toHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toHours()).

```
long hours = elapsed.toHours() ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).